# How to pipe files one by one from list into script?

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, ls

I have a list of files that I need to pipe into a shell script. I can list the files within a directory by using the following:

```
ls ~/data/2121/*SOMEFILE*
```

resulting in:

```
2121.SOMEFILEaa
2121.SOMEFILEab
2121.SOMEFILEac
and so on...
```

I have another script that performs some processing on a single file (2121.SOMEFILEaa) which I run by using the following command:

```
bash runscript ../data/2121/2121.SOMEFILEaa
```

However, I need to make this more efficient by piping individual files from the list of files generated via `ls` into the script. How can I pipe the results from the `ls ~/data/2121/*SOMEFILES*` command--file by file--into the `runscript` script?

Comment: Do you really want to pipe all the files into one instance of the script, or call the script multiple times, once for each file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
for file in ~/data/2121/*SOMEFILE*; do
    bash runscript "$file"
done
```

In this way, you're calling `bash runscript` for each file.

Answer (score 5):

Another option

```
ls ~/data/2121/*SOMEFILE* | xargs -L1 bash runscript
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat pipe.sh

#!/bin/bash
## Store data from pipe to variable $PIPE ------#
_read_pipe(){                                   #
    while read -t 10 pipe; do
        if [ -n "$pipe" ] ;then
            PIPE="$PIPE $pipe" ;fi ;done ;}


## your code -----------------------------------#
_read_pipe                                      #   
for kung_foo in $PIPE ;do
    echo $kung_foo ;done
```

---

```
$ ls 2121.SOMEFILE* | ./pipe.sh
2121.SOMEFILEaa
2121.SOMEFILEab
2121.SOMEFILEac
and so on...
```

[ -t ] is for timeout

I hope this helps,
cheers Karim